# Ab-initio method (First principle of Mathematics)

Tags: calculus

Who was the first one to give proof of 1st Principle of Mathematics in calculus (also known as ab-initio method) ,was he newton or someone else ??

Comment: Don't know much Latin but it seems to me this should be "initio", not "intio".  Try to add some sources to your question.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks man for correcting me :)

Comment: I think you are simply running into English terminology problem and nothing to do with history of maths and science. _ab initio_ is Latin for first principles, i.e. it does not make any more assumptions than what is already defined and assumed. It is not a method, just a separation between presenting things with additional assumptions versus not. More a teaching style than anything else.